# Multiple host, multiple credentials in Fabric python framework

Tags: python, ssh, credentials, fabric

I have 3 hosts. Each have same user but different password.

```
env.hosts = ['root@IP1','root@IP1','root@IP3' ]
# Set the password [NOT RECOMMENDED]
env.password = { 'root@IP1':'pass11' ,'root@IP1':'pass11','root@IP3':'pass' }
```

Tried this too

```
env.hosts = ['IP1','IP1','IP3' ]
# Set the username
env.user   = 'root'
# Set the password [NOT RECOMMENDED]
env.password = { 'IP1':'pass11' ,'IP1':'pass11','IP3':'pass' }
```

None of the above worked, fabric just gives the error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Can anyone point out the correct way to do this ?

I'm using fabric version '1.10.2'.

Comment: Did you try this: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/env.html#passwords

Comment: There's not enough info here - I suggest you create an MCVE and give the full stack trace.  Oh and your current example has an error (just 2 IP addresses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `env.passwords` (plural) instead of `env.password`, see [doc for more detail](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html#pre-filling-the-password-caches):

```
env.passwords = {'root@IP1': 'pass11' , 'root@IP1': 'pass11', 'root@IP3':'pass'}
```

---